# What is parameter name in PyArg_UnpackTuple (python c api) for?

Tags: python, c

This documentation http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#PyArg_UnpackTuple describes all the parameters of function, except for `const char *name`.

What is this parameter for? What should I put there and why?

Answer (score 5):

According to the Python source (Python/getargs.c), the name argument is used when raising exceptions. So it could be the name of the function/method in which you use PyArg_UnpackTuple.